# passing arrays to functions in x86 asm

Tags: windows, assembly, masm, masm32

I'm learning x86 asm and using masm, and am trying to write a function which has the equivalent signature to the following c function:

```
void func(double a[], double b[], double c[], int len);
```

I'm not sure how to implement it?

The asm file will be compiled into a win32 DLL.

So that I can understand how to do this, can someone please translate this very simple function into asm for me:

```
void func(double a[], double b[], double c[], int len)
{
  // a, b, and c have the same length, given by len
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

I tried writing a function like this in C, compiling it, and looking at the corresponding disassembled code in the exe using OllyDbg but I couldn't even find my function in it.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: why don't you poste here the ASM you got. maybe helpfull!

Comment: I don't have any yet... I roughly know what operations I need in the function but I don't know how to define the proc or how to reference the array variables. If I can see a translation of that loop I will know everything I need in order to write my ASM function.

Comment: sorry.... i mean the code u got using the compiler. I admit i never passed some arrays.... but maybe if i see the code generated by the compiler i get some ideas...:)

Comment: Ask the compiler to generate a .cod file. That contains the asm version of your function, ready to be assembled.

Comment: @Raymond Wow, I didn't know you could do that... I just tried it and it works. That's going to make learning ASM so much easer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't written x86 for a while but I can give you a general idea of how to do it. Since I don't have an assembler handy, this is written in notepad.

```
func proc a:DWORD, b:DWORD, c:DWORD, len:DWORD

  mov eax, len
  test eax, eax
  jnz @f
  ret

    @@:

  push ebx
  push esi

  xor eax, eax

  mov esi, a
  mov ebx, b
  mov ecx, c

    @@:

  mov edx, dword ptr ds:[ebx+eax*4]
  add edx, dword ptr ds:[ecx+eax*4]
  mov [esi+eax*4], edx
  cmp eax, len
  jl @b

  pop esi
  pop ebx

  ret  

func endp
```

The above function conforms to stdcall and is approximately how you would translate to x86 if your arguments were integers. Unfortunately, you are using doubles. The loop would be the same but you'd need to use the FPU stack and opcodes for doing the arithmetic. I haven't used that for a while and couldn't remember the instructions off the top of my head unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the memory addresses of the arrays. Consider the following code:

```
.data?
array1 DWORD 4 DUP(?)

.code
         main PROC

                      push LENGTHOF array1
                      push OFFSET array1
                      call arrayFunc             
         main ENDP

         arrayFunc PROC
                                   push ebp
                                   mov ebp, esp
                                   push edi

                                   mov edi, [ebp+08h] 
                                   mov ecx, [ebp+0Ch]
                                   L1:

                                  ;reference each element of given array by [edi]
                                  ;add "TYPE" *array* to edi to increment
                                   loop L1:
                                   pop edi
                                   pop ebp
                                   ret 8
         arrayFunc ENDP
         END main
```

I just wrote this code for you to understand the concept. I leave it to you to figure out how to properly figure the usage of registers in order to achieve your program's goals.